# Processes exceeding thread stack size limit on RedHat Enterprise Linux 6?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, pthreads, redhat, ulimit

I have a couple of processes running on RHEL 6.3, but for some reason they are exceeding the thread stack sizes.

For example, the Java process is given the stack size of -Xss256k at runtime on startup, and the C++ process is given a thread stack size of 1MB using pthread_attr_setstacksize() in the actual code.

For some reason however, these processes are not sticking to these limits, and I'm not sure why.

For example, when I run

```
pmap -x <pid>
```

for the C++ and Java process, I can see hundreds of 'anon' threads for each (which I have confirmed are the internal worker threads created by each of these processes), but these have an allocated value of 64MB each, not the limits set above:

```
00007fa4fc000000 168 40 40 rw--- [ anon ] 
00007fa4fc02a000 65368 0 0 ----- [ anon ] 
00007fa500000000 168 40 40 rw--- [ anon ] 
00007fa50002a000 65368 0 0 ----- [ anon ] 
00007fa504000000 168 40 40 rw--- [ anon ] 
00007fa50402a000 65368 0 0 ----- [ anon ] 
00007fa508000000 168 40 40 rw--- [ anon ] 
00007fa50802a000 65368 0 0 ----- [ anon ] 
00007fa50c000000 168 40 40 rw--- [ anon ] 
00007fa50c02a000 65368 0 0 ----- [ anon ] 
00007fa510000000 168 40 40 rw--- [ anon ] 
00007fa51002a000 65368 0 0 ----- [ anon ] 
00007fa514000000 168 40 40 rw--- [ anon ] 
00007fa51402a000 65368 0 0 ----- [ anon ] 
00007fa518000000 168 40 40 rw--- [ anon ] 
...
```

But when I run the following on the above process with all the 64MB 'anon' threads

```
cat /proc/<pid>/limits | grep stack 

Max stack size 1048576 1048576 bytes
```

it shows a max thread stack size of 1MB, so am a bit confused as to what is going on here. Also, the script that calls these programs sets 'ulimit -s 1024' as well.

It should be noted that this only seems to occur when using a very high end machines (e.g. 48GB RAM, 24 CPU cores). The issue does not appear on less powerful machines (e.g. 4GB RAM, 2 CPU cores).

Any help understanding what is happening here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out that RHEL6 2.11 have changed the thread model such that each thread where possible gets allocated its own thread pool, so on a larger system you may see it grabbing up to the 64MB. On 64 bit the max number of thread pools allowed is greater.

The fix for this was to add

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libtcmalloc.so
```

in the script that starts the processes (rather than using glibc2.11)

Some more inforation on this is available from:

Linux glibc >= 2.10 (RHEL 6) malloc may show excessive virtual memory usage
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/kevgrig/entry/linux_glibc_2_10_rhel_6_malloc_may_show_excessive_virtual_memory_usage?lang=en

glibc bug malloc uses excessive memory for multi-threaded applications 
http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11261

Apache hadoop have fixed the problem by setting MALLOC_ARENA_MAX 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7154

Comment: Thanks for this answer, saved me a lot of time!
why make this change and released without any alerts?

Answer (score 0):

The stack size as reported with `/proc/1234/limits` is set with [setrlimit(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) (perhaps by [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_PAM) subsystem at login time).

I have no real idea as to why the actual stack segments seems to be 64Mb each. Perhaps your big server uses [huge pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huge_pages) (but your desktop don't).

You might call `setrlimit` (perhaps with the `ulimit` bash builtin, or the `limit` zsh builtin) in e.g. the script calling your program.

Comment: Thanks Basile - I am doing as you say - setting ulimit -s 1024 in the script that calls the program, but still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ulimit -s <size_in_KB>` to set the maximum stack size for processes. You can see the current limit using `ulimit -s` too.

Comment: Thanks Spap, I am doing this already in the script that starts these processes - it doesn't seem to affect anything, apologies for not mentioning, I've updated my post above to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

@rory With reagard to your answer, the 64mb block address should be heap address, but now the address is like 00007fa50c02a000 that is stack address, right?